# Creating a subset based on the branching logic

Tags: r

I need to include or exclude the variable from a data set based on the factor variable (branching logic).
If var 1 = 1 then include var2 and var3, otherwise exclude.
I tried:

```
Newdf<- ifelse((var1 == "1",c(var2),c(-var2)) ,
ifelse((var1 == "1",c(var3),c(-var3))
```

And with dplyr:

```
Newdf<- df %>%
select( if_else(var1== 1,var2,-var2))%>%
select( if_else(var1== 1,var3,-var3))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Just subset using `%in%`.

```
dat
#   var1 var2 var3
# 1    1   21   31
# 2    1   22   32
# 3    1   23   33
# 4    0   24   34
# 5    0   25   35
# 6    1   26   36

dat2 <- dat[dat$var1 %in% 1, ]
dat2
#   var1 var2 var3
# 1    1   21   31
# 2    1   22   32
# 3    1   23   33
# 6    1   26   36
```

Or, if you depend on `ifelse` do

```
dat[with(dat, ifelse(var1 %in% 1, TRUE, FALSE)), ]
#   var1 var2 var3
# 1    1   21   31
# 2    1   22   32
# 3    1   23   33
# 6    1   26   36
```

*Note:* We need `%in%` because `==` won't work when there are NA present in the data.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), var2 = 21:26, 
    var3 = 31:36), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```